# Problemas com Gson do Google: Unparseable date: "abr 19, 1991"

Tags: java, data, gson

Trabalho com Gson do Google, para persistir e recuperar Objetos Java. Uso esse código para criar e formatar o Gson, com o Objetivo de prepapará-lo para receber certos formatos de datas, que vem de formulários e do banco de dados.

```
Gson g = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateDeserializer()).create();
```

Essa é a classe DateDeserializer, que recebe um Gson e faz um parse com formatos de Datas, evitando a grande maioria dos erros.

```
public class DateDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Date> {

private static final String[] DATE_FORMATS = new String[]{
    "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss",
    "MMM dd, yyyy",
    "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "mmm dd, yyyy",
    "yyyy/MM/dd",
    "yyyy-MM-dd",
    "dd-MM-yyyy"
};

@Override
public Date deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc) throws JsonParseException {
    for (String format : DATE_FORMATS) {
        try {
            return new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.ROOT).parse(jsonElement.getAsString());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
        }
    }
    throw new JsonParseException("Unparseable date: \"" + jsonElement.getAsString()
            + "\". Supported formats: " + Arrays.toString(DATE_FORMATS));
}
```

}

O problema é no formato que pus no título: **"abr 19, 1991"**.
Sempre gera esse erro: **Unparseable date**, por mais que eu ja tenha colocado diversos formatos dentro da classe de Deserialização. Alguém já passou por isso ou sabe como solucionar..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem, consegui resolver implementado a classe dessa maneira:

```
public class DateDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Date> {

private static final String[] DATE_FORMATS = new String[]{
    "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss",
    "MMM dd, yyyy",
    "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "mmm dd, yyyy",
    "yyyy/MM/dd",
    "yyyy-MM-dd",
    "dd-MM-yyyy"
};

@Override
public Date deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc) throws JsonParseException {
    for (String format : DATE_FORMATS) {
        try {
            return new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.ROOT).parse(jsonElement.getAsString());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
        }
        try {
            return new SimpleDateFormat(format, new Locale("pt", "BR")).parse(jsonElement.getAsString());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
        }
    }
    throw new JsonParseException("Unparseable date: \"" + jsonElement.getAsString()
            + "\". Supported formats: " + Arrays.toString(DATE_FORMATS));
}
```

}

Fica a solução aqui para quem tiver o mesmo problema.